# Hands-On Enterprise Application Development with Java 9 no Liberty Server showing on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, open-liberty

I am trying to learn in Udemy the Hands-On Enterprise Application Development with Java 9 and I tried finding the same version on Open Liberty and the version available for development builds was 2020-08-26, 15:23. I downloaded that and extracted and saw that there was no "wlp" folder.

I also tried the eclipse wherein I tried to define a new server and there was no Liberty Server as shown on the course. I installed the Developer tool from the marketplace. It is my first time trying this so I apologize if I do not know much about how to setup the softwares needed. Is this because the setups from the tutorials are outdated? i am currently using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers and downloaded the Open Liberty development builds 2020-08-26, 15:23.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to download Eclipse from here https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2022-03/r/eclipse-ide-enterprise-java-and-web-developers
The last supported version right now is 22-03 as I see on marketplace (always run with the recent versions) https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-liberty-developer-tools

Start your Eclipse, drag `Install` button from market place to your open Eclipse window. The plugin installation should start.
Once the plugin is installed go to the `Servers` view

- click `Create new server`, choose `IBM > Liberty Server`
- In the Liberty Runtime window choose "Install from an archive or a repository"
- Then select "Download and install a new runtime..."
- From the list select one that you are interested, if you are just starting with Java EE 8 use "WAS Liberty with Java EE 8 Full Platform" and then select Java EE 8 bundle to install.

You should have Liberty installed and visible in the Servers view. You can double click it to edit Liberty configuration, and also start/stop server from that view.